# attempting to create a script, with an alias, that will backup a single file

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

I want to do this. I want to create an alias called 'bu' (backup). The bu alias would call upon the copy tool to copy any file passed to a directory I will manually setup in /root/backup/

```
$bu testfile.txt
```

cp testfile.txt /root/backup/

So I think I need to create a bash script, and point the alias to that script ( could be wrong here), but im not sure how to approach the bash script to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to copy only one file at once or any number of files? Also do you *need* an alias? If you write a script anyways you might just name that `bu` and have no need for an alias.

Comment: just a single file at once. No I dont have to have an alias, as long as I can call the script globally without having to do something like ...   /path/to/script./bu /path/to/file/file1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bash script called `bu`. Put this code inside a file `bu`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp "$1" /root/backup
```

and then save it in your `$PATH` or add the directory where you put the file to your `$PATH`. Lastly make the script executable: `chmod +x bu`.

Comment: I think this is exactly what im looking for. Your $1 lead me to look up and read about positional parameters - very interesting. Can you confirm where the best place is to add the path to PATH? Should I just check the current PATH and place it in the existing path locations, or should I add a new path to .bashrc or .bash_profile. Not sure of the difference

Comment: Many people use `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or even `~/.local/bin` for their scripts. Chances are some of these are already in your `$PATH` (execute `echo $PATH` to see if that's the case). There is no best place. It is your choice/taste. The only thing to think about is if you are the only user who will need that script or if other users who need it also have the right directory in their path (e.g `root`?).